# how to map the splited String to a class?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have load a table from HDFS and the table acctually has 300 columns.but what I load is a table with ONE column names value and the orginal values of columns every row are together in this one colunm spliting with "/t".

like this

```
+——————————+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|1489763115 SS EN-...|
|1489763140 SS EN-...|
|1489763552 SS EN-...|
|1489763552 PE EN-...|
|1489763553 PE EN-...|
|1489763554 PE EN-...|
|1489763585 SS EN-...|
```

what I need to do is split the long String each row to 300 columns from one colunms,and make it as Json.
So i try to turn the dataset(RDD String) to a Array, and take each line to map to the class .and turn the new dataset to String.

there is my code:

```
//this is the class I want to map to 

case class MapThing(gmt:Int,Name:String,Language:String,.....500 of them)


//data is the RDD[String] I get from the HDFS

val packagesRDD = data
val packagesDF = data.toDF
packagesDF.show(false)
/*

+——————————+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|1489763115 SS EN-...|
|1489763140 SS EN-...|
|1489763552 SS EN-...|
|1489763552 PE EN-...|
|1489763553 PE EN-...|
|1489763554 PE EN-...|
|1489763585 SS EN-...|

*/

//here to process the data:
    data.map(line => {
      var arr = line.split("/t",-1)
      OmnitureHitHourly(arr(0).toInt,arr(1),arr(2),arr(3),arr(4).,arr(5)....arr(299))
}).toJSON
```

But the split cannot be recognized by IDE.

and I also try:

```
val array = packagesDF.collect()
packagesDF.collect()
.foreach(row => {row.get(0).toString
.map(line=>{
val arr = line.split("/t",-1)
```

OmnitureHitHourly(arr(0).toInt,arr(1),arr(2),arr(3),arr(4).,arr(5)....arr(299)) }
     )})
     .toJSON

it throw a stackoverflow exception..

==============================================================================

here is now what I write,

```
 case class ThingNeedMap(
                                  gmt : String,//Int
                                  name : String,//BigInt
                                  language : String,//BigInt
                                  date_time : String,
                              ...500 fielsd

                                )


    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    println("Data: ", data)
    val packagesRDD = data
//    val packagesDF = data.toDF
    val packagesDF = data.toDF
    data.map(line => {
      val arr = line.split("/t",-1)
      ThingNeedMap(arr(0),arr(1),arr(2),arr(3),arr(4),arr(5),arr(6),arr(7),arr(8),arr(9),arr(10),
        arr(11),arr(12),arr(13),arr(14),arr(15),arr(16),arr(17),arr(18),arr(19),arr(20),
        arr(21),arr(22),arr(23),arr(24),arr(25),arr(26),arr(27),arr(28),arr(29),arr(30),
        arr(31),arr(32),arr(33),arr(34),arr(35),arr(36),arr(37),arr(38),arr(39),arr(40),
        arr(41),arr(42),arr(43),arr(44),arr(45),arr(46),arr(47),arr(48),arr(49),arr(50),
        arr(51),arr(52),arr(53),arr(54),arr(55),arr(56),arr(57),arr(58),arr(59),arr(60),
        arr(61),arr(62),arr(63),arr(64),arr(65),arr(66),arr(67),arr(68),arr(69),arr(70),
        arr(71),arr(72),arr(73),arr(74),arr(75),arr(76),arr(77),arr(78),arr(79),arr(80),
        arr(81),arr(82),arr(83),arr(84),arr(85),arr(86),arr(87),arr(88),arr(89),arr(90),
        arr(91),arr(92),arr(93),arr(94),arr(95),arr(96),arr(97),arr(98),arr(99),arr(100),
        arr(101),arr(102),arr(103),arr(104),arr(105),arr(106),arr(107),arr(108),arr(109),arr(110),
        arr(111),arr(112),arr(113),arr(114),arr(115),arr(116),arr(117),arr(118),arr(119),arr(120),
        arr(121),arr(122),arr(123),arr(124),arr(125),arr(126),arr(127),arr(128),arr(129),arr(130),
        arr(131),arr(132),arr(133),arr(134),arr(135),arr(136),arr(137),arr(138),arr(139),arr(140),
        arr(141),arr(142),arr(143),arr(144),arr(145),arr(146),arr(147),arr(148),arr(149),arr(150),
        arr(151),arr(152),arr(153),arr(154),arr(155),arr(156),arr(157),arr(158),arr(159),arr(160),
        arr(161),arr(162),arr(163),arr(164),arr(165),arr(166),arr(167),arr(168),arr(169),arr(170),
        arr(171),arr(172),arr(173),arr(174),arr(175),arr(176),arr(177),arr(178),arr(179),arr(180),
        arr(181),arr(182),arr(183),arr(184),arr(185),arr(186),arr(187),arr(188),arr(189),arr(190),
        arr(191),arr(192),arr(193),arr(194),arr(195),arr(196),arr(197),arr(198),arr(199),arr(200),
        arr(201),arr(202),arr(203),arr(204),arr(205),arr(206),arr(207),arr(208),arr(209),arr(210),
        arr(211),arr(212),arr(213),arr(214),arr(215),arr(216),arr(217),arr(218),arr(219),arr(220),
        arr(221),arr(222),arr(223),arr(224),arr(225),arr(226),arr(227),arr(228),arr(229),arr(230),
        arr(231),arr(232),arr(233),arr(234),arr(235),arr(236),arr(237),arr(238),arr(239),arr(240),
        arr(241),arr(242),arr(243),arr(244),arr(245),arr(246),arr(247),arr(248),arr(249),arr(250),
        arr(251),arr(252),arr(253),arr(254),arr(255),arr(256),arr(257),arr(258),arr(259),arr(260),
        arr(261),arr(262),arr(263),arr(264),arr(265),arr(266),arr(267),arr(268),arr(269),arr(270),
        arr(271),arr(272),arr(273),arr(274),arr(275),arr(276),arr(277),arr(728),arr(279),arr(280),
        arr(281),arr(282),arr(283),arr(284),arr(285),arr(286),arr(287),arr(288),arr(289),arr(290),
        arr(291),arr(292),arr(293),arr(294),arr(295),arr(296),arr(297),arr(298),arr(299),arr(300),
        arr(301),arr(302),arr(303),arr(304),arr(305),arr(306),arr(307),arr(308),arr(309),arr(310),
        arr(311),arr(312),arr(313),arr(314),arr(315),arr(316),arr(317),arr(318),arr(319),arr(320),
        arr(321),arr(322),arr(323),arr(324),arr(325),arr(326),arr(327),arr(328),arr(329),arr(330),
        arr(331),arr(332),arr(333),arr(334),arr(335),arr(336),arr(337),arr(338),arr(339),arr(340),
        arr(341),arr(342),arr(343),arr(344),arr(345),arr(346),arr(347),arr(348),arr(349),arr(350),
        arr(351),arr(352),arr(353),arr(354),arr(355),arr(356),arr(357),arr(358),arr(359),arr(360),
        arr(361),arr(362),arr(363),arr(364),arr(365),arr(366),arr(367),arr(368),arr(369),arr(370),
        arr(371),arr(372),arr(373),arr(374),arr(375),arr(376),arr(377),arr(378),arr(379),arr(380),
        arr(381),arr(382),arr(383),arr(384),arr(385),arr(386),arr(387),arr(388),arr(389),arr(390),
        arr(391),arr(392),arr(393),arr(394),arr(395),arr(396),arr(397),arr(398),arr(399),arr(400),
        arr(401),arr(402),arr(403),arr(404),arr(405),arr(406),arr(407),arr(408),arr(409),arr(410),
        arr(411),arr(412),arr(413),arr(414),arr(415),arr(416),arr(417),arr(418),arr(419),arr(420),
        arr(421),arr(422),arr(423),arr(424),arr(425))

    }).toJSON
```

and throw a exception..

```
Error:scalac: Error: org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.ServerException
java.lang.StackOverflowError    at scala.reflect.internal.util.Collections$class.mapList(Collections.scala:52)
```

Is there other better way to escape the mapping step? I only want a json that with key and value ..and the key is the column from the old table,not this one that only get one column.

Comment: Did you mean to split on `\t`?

Comment: yes..and this is not a problem.My problem is how to make every row split and map to the class. and then can turn to json

Answer (score 1):

No sane program has classes with 300 or 500 or whatever fields. So the compiler isn't tested with them, and its internal methods and data structures break down. Fixing this would take a huge amount of effort for very little reason (except in hopes that improvements would filter down to sane programs, but improving performance on them directly takes obvious priority). You could try buying a supercomputer just to compile your programs (don't).

Spark probably wouldn't have similar problems with dataframes this wide, but I am not sure. But you have no need for either: just map your `RDD[String]` to your desired JSON directly using Jackson, which Spark itself uses:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes._
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.JsonNodeFactory

val fields = sc.broadcast(Array(("gmt", IntegerType), ("name", StringType), ...))

data.map { line =>
  val arr = line.split("\t", -1)
  val jsonObjectNode = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode()
  for { ((fieldName, fieldType), value) <- fields.value.zip(arr) }
    fieldType match {
      case IntegerType =>
        jsonObjectNode.put(fieldName, value.toInt)
      case DoubleType =>
        jsonObjectNode.put(fieldName, value.toDouble)
      ...
    }
    (new ObjectMapper).writeValueAsString(jsonObjectNode)
}
```

Or something like that.
I've checked and the compiler seems to handle hundreds of vararg arguments just fine, but if you run into problems there, just load them from a file or concatenate a few arrays.

Comment: which version of jackson so you use? the function writeValueAsString cannot load...it is red in intelliJ

Comment: Is there other better way to escape the mapping step? I only want a json that with key and value ..and the key is the column from the old table,not this one that only get one column..

Comment: Typo, forgot the parentheses. But as I said, the point is that you can easily build whatever JSON you want without having to invent useless classes. Just read Jackson docs/tutorials and ask questions about that part if you need help.